# error: No SCREEN available: You can't launch nodes

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using node_manager_fkie from multimaster_fkie. And when I run node_manager, this error will appear. When I tried launching a node, this error will appear: usr/bin/screen is missing. Furthermore, on the GUI, "ROS NETWORK [disabled]" is displayed. What am I supposed to do so I am able to run a node?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/293986/error:-no-screen-available:-you-can%27t-launch-nodes./) by [amelia](https://answers.ros.org/users/35848/amelia/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2018-06-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To solve for the error: No SCREEN available: You can't launch nodes.
You will need to install screen. (sudo apt install screen)

Regarding the network is disabled, it is another problem, I will open another question about it.

All thanks to Alexander Tiderko for replying my email!

---

Originally posted by [amelia](https://answers.ros.org/users/35848/amelia/) with karma: 18 on 2018-06-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0